# Write application indicator with no icon

Tags: application-development, python, indicator, icons

I wrote an application indicator that displays information about my monthly network consumption.
I do not want it to have an icon next to the text I display.
How do I write an application indicator without an icon?

The code I use to initialize my indicator is:

```
self.indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new("VooMeter", "network", appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
```

Reading the documentation I can not find the value to put instead of "network"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some code tries, I couldn't find a way either and reading the docs, I don't think it's possible. Here's something interesting from the `label` property:

> The label will not be shown unless there is an icon as well.

So, if there is a way to disable the icon, it won't even show the label.

Comment: Your right, I wonder what library xfce4-netload-plugin use to show text in the panel without an icon

Comment: Did you progress any further with this?

Comment: Looking at a quick glance, `xfce4-netload-plugin` doesn't use the Unity appindicator framework. A little hack would be to create an empty or little transparent image and add that.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. As a workaround I have used one pixel wide transparent image as icon.